A linear algebra exercise relating to Inner Product Spaces
Let $\left\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\right\}$ be a (not necessarily the standard) basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$ be given for $1 \leq i \leq n$. Show that there exists a unique vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x \cdot v_i=\alpha_i$ for all $i$. Hint: Think of a linear map!
How to approach this question?
P.S. This is Exercise 5.1.8 from the book Linear Algebra - A geometric approach by S Kumaresan

What did you try?

You should post your attempt at the question.

My request to people who downvote, please give some explanation.

Hint:
If you define the square matrix $\mathbf{V} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (recall that matrices represent linear maps), and the vector $\boldsymbol{\alpha} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ as:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{V} &:= \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{v}_1 \\
\vdots \\
\mathbf{v}_n
\end{pmatrix}
&
\boldsymbol{\alpha} &:= \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 \\ \vdots \\\alpha_n \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$
Then the question is equivalent to showing that there exists a solution, $\mathbf{x}$ to the equation $\mathbf{V}\mathbf{x} = \boldsymbol{\alpha}$. Given that $\{ \mathbf{v}_1, \dots, \mathbf{v}_n \}$ forms a basis, what can you say about the rows of $\mathbf{V}$? Does this tell you anything else that is interesting about $\mathbf{V}$?

This reduces the problem to solving n equations in n unknowns, which must have a unique solution, is that it?

@Tanush Something like that. However, $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns don't necessarily have a unique solution. Try thinking about some conditions on the matrix $\mathbf{V}$ that are equivalent to the solution being unique.

Please read this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1
